# How to define custom header inside screen in react navigation 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

i know we use options prop when we define screen in root file

```
 <Stack.Screen
          name="index"
          component={Index}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            headerRight: (props) => (
              <MaterialIcons name="add" size={30} style={{ marginRight: 20 }} />
            ),
          })}
        />
```

But i want to define in the screen by itself like we used to do in react navigation 4

```
Index.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerRight: (
      <MaterialIcons name="add" size={30} style={{ marginRight: 20 }} />
    ),
  };
};
```

but how i can do it in react navigation 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use *navigation.setOptions*

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <MaterialIcons name="add" size={30} style={{ marginRight: 20 }} />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Help me with this issue if you can? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606346/react-navigation-v5-pass-function-as-parameter-to-be-used-in-headerright-butto

Comment: I am adding button just like this but can't call a function passed as param